# Docker container cannot find Django package

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, anaconda3

I am new to docker. I am trying to dockerize a simple django app, which I create in anaconda3 in ubuntu.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Pull base image
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirement.txt /code/
RUN conda install --file requirement.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

The `requirement.txt` is the list of dependency packages from my conda virtual enviroment. I obtain that by running this line in my conda activated environment:

`conda list -e > requirement.txt`
and the package `django=3.0.3=py_0` is in this `requirement.txt`

Also, at this point, I have properly installed docker and pulled the base image `continuumio/anaconda3`.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Now, when I run `docker-compose up`, I got this chain of error messages (by this point, all the dependency packages in `requirement.txt` have been installed):

```
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 10, in main
web_1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
web_1  | 
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  | 
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
web_1  |     main()
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 16, in main
web_1  |     ) from exc
web_1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
hello_project_web_1 exited with code 1
```

My questions: what am I doing wrong? Why is docker asking for an activation of a virtual environment? Isn't the container itself now the "virtual environment"?

I have seen a working example using "pip" [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/). But I am used to conda and would love to figure this out.

Thanks,

Comment: I ran your image in my machine and it worked without any problem. I use MacOS

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out the problem. I installed django in a folder one level diferent from the app folder.